# where statement not working only for a particular column in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am trying to make a very basic sql query from a mysql table.

```
SELECT VAV,floor from Mapping limit 10;
```

output is

[image]

But when I try with

```
 SELECT VAV,floor from Mapping where floor='B2WL1';
```

It outputs an empty set. I am very surprised with this. I have also tried with spaces like

```
 SELECT VAV,floor from Mapping where floor=' B2WL1'; 
 SELECT VAV,floor from Mapping where floor='B2WL1 ';
```

it is returning empty set. Can someone help me with this. Really stuck at this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: There may be other blank characters in your record, copy it all into `Notepad ++` and enable `Show All Characters`

Comment: Not reproducible, based on the data shown. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c34cea1b0feeae4205356f99cd01e21 . As others have mentioned, you probably have some other hidden characters. What's the encoding of the column / table / database?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 where floor like '%B2WL1%';
```

Comment: floor i am passing as a variable in my python script. when I use `where floor like '%%s%';` it gives an error ``` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'B2WL1'%)```

Comment: I don't know Phyton maybe you can try :
     '%%%s%%'

Answer (score 1):

Probably has whitespaces or any other hidden characters

you may try with wild characters like

```
SELECT VAV,floor, LENGTH(floor) as number_of_characters 
from Mapping 
where floor like '%B2WL1%';
```